# Linear programming: Maximize minimum of linear functions

Tags: linear-programming

For a project I need something solved, it screams linear programming.
If I get the problem in "standard" form I should be able to solve it using the simplex method. But I don't see how to get it in standard form. The problem is this:

Maximize $$min(f_1(\lambda),...,f_p(\lambda))$$
s.t $\sum \lambda_i=1,\lambda_i \geq 0$

where $\lambda=(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ and $f_i$ linear.

Help or direction to a good source would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check section 7 in Thomas Ferguson's "Linear Programming": http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/LP.pdf. There might be something useful.

Answer (score 9):

This is a basic case of optimiation problem easy to be cast as a linear one, you can find it in any textbook.

$\max t$

$ t\leq f_i(\lambda),\quad i=1...$

$\sum \lambda_i = 1$

$\lambda_i\geq 0, \quad i=1...$

Comment: This is now the top result for the Google search 'maximize minimum of linear functions'. It's feels a bit condescending to read that one should search carefully before trying to find an answer in SE.

Comment: Well, when I wrote the answer it was not....I found things like http://www.4er.org/CourseNotes/Book%20A/A-III.pdf

Comment: How can it be solved? By simplex method? if so, is there any demonstration? Also, could someone provide some references about the computational complexity of this problem?

Comment: Any linear programming solver would do (it will use either simplex or interior point algorithm under the hood). As for complexity, linear programming is broadly speaking polynomially solvable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Algorithms).

Comment: I found that the proof of the time complexity in this maximin problem is missing. Are there any references? Thank you!